# AWS Lambda error There was an error loading Log Streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When I go to the Logs page the below error shows.

> There was an error loading Log Streams. Please try again by refreshing this page.

Problem is there is another function that is identical except the code that is creating log files no problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

I solved it.

I added  CloudwatchLogsFullAccess and then it took some time under an hour and then it was working.

I'm not sure why I needed to do this for the second function but not the first but it's working now.

Below is the link that helped me.

https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/02/12/error-loading-log-streams/

Comment: (Commenting this is not necessarily to dissuade using 'CloudwatchLogsFullAccess' policy mentioned in this Answer, but rather to point out other policy options too) -  A policy with as much access as 'CloudwatchLogsFullAccess' may not be necessary:  My Lambda uses just 'AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole' [an AWS managed policy] (which has only 'Write' access level), and can view logs with just that.

Comment: For me to make the Policy modification to take effect I had to do a minor modification in the Lambda and press "Save". Once I did this, the Policy update started taking effect instantly.

Answer (score 7):

**Make sure your Lambda has already logged at least once!**

Appears to me that this error occurs if that is not the case - I've tested fresh Lambdas both with and without any log statements to confirm:  Without any log statements, a corresponding Log Group for the Lambda does not exist yet; after the first log statement is made, the statement then exists in a seemingly-newly-made corresponding Log Group.

Although this may seem obvious/intuitive after-the-fact, this is how I ran into this scenario:  I think before any logging had occurred on my new Lambda, I tried to hook it up to CloudWatch events - I tried after that attempt to see if the Lambda was invoked (by the events) via viewing *'Monitoring' tab -> 'View logs in CloudWatch' button* - and that is where I encountered this error.  The Lambda had not been invoked [CloudWatch events hookup had failed], so no logging had occurred, and thus there was no corresponding Log Group made yet to examine (when trying to hyperlink into it from the Lambda Configuration).

(Fwiw, I imagine maybe a corresponding Log Group could be manually made before the first logging, but I have not tested that.)

Comment: This is a separate Answer from my other Answer because, although BOTH need to be applied, you may already be in the position where the other is already applied & you only need to now apply apply this Answer.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem

Comment: If you are using AWS Lambda and click "Test" for your test, you will first have to name your Test. Then when you click "Ok", that is not actually going to run a test for you, it just defined the test name. So if you immediately check the Logs, you won't see anything. You have to click "Test" a *second* time.

Comment: Your answer saved me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Ensure your Lambda's Execution Role has a Policy that allows writing to CloudWatch Logs from your Lambda.**

*IAM console -> 'Roles' -> < your Lambda's role > -> 'Permissions' tab -> 'Permissions policies' accordion*

Ensure there is a Policy listed that has parameters set like this:

- 'Service': "CloudWatch Logs"
- 'Access level': includes at least "Write"
- 'Resource':  your Lambda is not excluded (i.e: its not set to another specific Lambda, or another directory of Lambdas, or another resource type)
- 'Request condition': does not preclude the context of your given Lambda execution

An example of an "AWS managed policy" that meets these requirements [out-of-the-box, being that it is AWS-managed] is *"**AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole**"*.  It has these parameters:

- 'Service': "CloudWatch Logs"
- 'Access level': "Limited: Write"
- 'Resource':  "All resources"
- 'Request condition': "None"

If your Role does not have such a policy already, either add a new one or edit and existing one to have the requirements listed here - then this error should be resolved.

For example, in my case before I fixed things, my Lambda's Role had a policy that was *based* off [AWS-managed] "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole", but somehow had a Resource that was limited to a different Lambda (which was my problem - insufficient permission to meet that policy from my different intended Lambda).  I fixed this by adding the *original* [AWS-managed] "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" Policy to my intended Lambda's role (I also deleted the prior-said Policy as it wasn't used by anything else, but that probably wasn't strictly necessary [although nice to tidy up]).

Comment: This is a separate Answer from my other Answer because, although BOTH need to be applied, you may already be in the position where the other is already applied & you only need to now apply apply this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by attaching CloudWatchFullAccess policy to the execution role of my lambda function [image]